# XSLT check value against enumeration or default to something else

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm attempting to convert a Time Zone value from one system to a different value to be pushed to another.

All good I wish they had of used state names instead of city names but never mind, this is an integration and can not be changed in both systems to just match each other.

I'm using XSLT to translate 1 xml document to another to do this.

In **source** system the time zone string one of the following:

```
Australia/Adelaide
Australia/Brisbane
Australia/Canberra
Australia/Darwin
Australia/Hobart
Australia/Melbourne
Australia/Perth
Australia/Sydney
```

In the **target** system the time zones are set up as per the following:

```
Australia/Adelaide
Australia/Brisbane
Australia/Canberra,Melbourne,Sydney
Australia/Darwin
Australia/Hobart
Australia/Perth
```

I know I can just use a `<xsl:choose>` and use `<xs:when>` etc to determine each string, but wanted to learn how to compare what's coming in from source against the enumeration source type, if it exists use it, if it doesn't exist then use a default value. Is this possible.

My enumeration in the **xslt** is defined per the target system as that what's required:

```
<xs:simpleType name="timeZoneType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Australia/Canberra,Melbourne,Sydney" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Australia/Adelaide" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Australia/Brisbane" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Australia/Darwin" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Australia/Hobart" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Australia/Perth" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Cheers in advance for any help

Comment: Please state XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: BTW: "*I wish they had of used state names instead of city names*" You should have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Hi Michael, using xslt 1 at the moment.

Comment: "*using xslt 1 at the moment*" Then you won't be able to use schema. I am not sure how your enumeration would help in this anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 processor you can do

```
<xsl:if test="$in castable as timeZoneType">
```

If you can't, then you'll have to hand-craft it. You could of course generate the XSLT code by processing your schema document through an XSLT transformation.

Comment: Thanks Michael am using this through apache camel and didn't want to use camel-saxon if i didn't have to. But this helps the learning, which was the main point of the questions, thanks again

Comment: I am not quite sure how that would work. A source value of "Australia/Canberra" would fail the above test; how does that lead to selecting "Australia/Canberra,Melbourne,Sydney" as the replacement value?

Comment: It does the first part of the job, "if it exists (in the list) then use it". You can put the other part "if it doesn't exist" in the other branch of the logic.

Comment: Cheers guys. As per M.Kay response, it does the first part if its in enumeratated list. And you are correct it does not work in xslt 1.0 but does in 2.0 so while i can't use it in what im doing. Its stored in the memory banks for when i come across it again :)

Answer (score 1):

> wanted to learn how to compare what's coming in from source against
>   the enumeration source type, if it exists use it, if it doesn't exist
>   then use a default value.

In XSLT 1.0 (at least), I believe it would be best to use an external lookup table in XML format, for example:

```
<lookup>
    <entry>
        <input>Australia/Canberra</input>
        <input>Australia/Melbourne</input>
        <input>Australia/Sydney</input>
        <output>Australia/Canberra,Melbourne,Sydney</output>
    </entry>
</lookup>
```

If the source value matches one of the input values, you would use the matching entry's output value as the output; otherwise the source input value gets passed to the output *as is*.

Note that your schema does not provide the necessary information to effect this replacement.